# Session scoped bean in view with Spring 3

Tags: session, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have the next bean:

```
@Component
@ComponentScan("es.pys.model")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Sesion {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

That I am using in several Controllers.

```
@Autowired
private Sesion sesion;
```

And I want to use it in my view too (example):

```
<spring:message code="welcome" arguments="${fn:escapeXml(sesion.name)}" htmlEscape="false"/>
```

The problem is that the line before doesn't work because `sesion` doesn't exist.

How can I access my bean, **and only this bean**, in all my views?
I've been reading solutions like:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list>
             <value>sesion</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The thing is that I need to define my bean in `applicationContext.xml` instead of using annotations, or am I wrong?

Ideas?

Thanks!.

Comment: It doesn't matter how your bean is defined (xml, annotations, java-config or properties) as long as the name matches it will be exposed.

Comment: The `@ComponentScan` on your `@Component` doesn't make any sense, nor does anything in this location.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your servlet-context.xml

Comment: Hey Philipp Sander. I already have that line in my servlet-context.